# Evolution of Enlightenment starting from Benedict de Spinoza

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, enlightenment

I want to learn about the evolution of enlightenment starting from Benedict de Spinoza. Can anybody name a good book with a link to the e-book?

Comment: what do you mean by the *evolution of enlightenment*?

Answer (score 2):

[The Rise of Modern Philosophy: A New History of Western Philosophy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064A4XP8) 
"An accurate summary of what each of the major figures had to say, and then a perceptive analysis of the philosophical consequences. Kenny makes reading the history of philosophy great fun. It is ideal as the first thing to read for someone new to this wonderfully creative period. Sir Anthony Kenny is one of Britain's most distinguished academic figures. He has been Pro-Vice-Chancellor of the University of Oxford, Master of Balliol College, Chairman of the Board of the British Library, and President of the British Academy. He has published more than forty books on philosophy and history."

Answer (score 0):

Try Jonathan Israel, https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Radical_Enlightenment.html?id=vMvlEweVPTsC&redir_esc=y
It's Spinoza, from the beginning.     A controversial, brilliant, fascinating story.    You can do well with some of the book reviews to start, see e.g. https://www.lrb.co.uk/v34/n21/margaret-jacob/spinoza-got-it